# How do I create a git repository on our shared server?

Tags: git

Can someone walk me through a few steps with git?  I'm wasting hours trying to do stuff that supposedly is simple.

I have a server called MyServer.  It has a shared folder, CodeInGit, on it.  I want to create a VS 2010 project called MyProject.  (For starters, a blank solution file is sufficient.)  I want to create a repository specific to this project.

What I want to do is:

1. Create a repository on MyServer under its C:\CodeInGit\MyProject.
2. Create my local repository, in C:\Users\me\CodeInGit\MyProject.
3. Create the solution file (MyProject.sln) in C:\Users\me\CodeInGit\MyProject
4. Add, commit, and push the solution file.

(I have git installed on the server and my PC.  I've run through numerous rounds of `git init` or `git init --bare` and, after a plethora of error messages, I think it's better if I yield to someone who has a clue about how to do this correctly.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the server:

```
cd c:\CodeInGit\MyProject
git init --bare
```

Locally, assuming that the server directory `c:\CodeInGit\MyProject` is mounted as `\\servername\MyProject`:

```
cd c:\Users\me\CodeInGit\MyProject
git clone //servername/MyProject .
```

Create the Visual Studio solution in `c:\Users\me\CodeInGit\MyProject`, then

```
git add MySolution.sln
git commit -m "New solution added."
git push origin master
```

You will probably also want to create a file called `.gitignore` with the following contents:

```
bin
obj
*.suo
*.user
```

so that compiled files and files containing user-specific settings won't accidentally get added to the repository. Then, add and commit `.gitignore`.

Comment: Good gravy, that worked.  It doesn't seem that different from the 100 things I already tried, but there must be some essential piece I kept missing.  Thank you, I shall cherish this answer to the end of my days.

Comment: Glad it helped (and thanks for the most appreciative "thank you" I've received so far). :-) Who knows how many times I myself have been searching for hours for the right combination of commands to achieve something... The most magic part of this is `git clone`, which initializes the local repository, adds the server repository as a remote repository, fetches the history from the remote repository, checks out the `master` branch and sets it to track the `master` branch from the remote repository.

Comment: Also, if you already have a local repository that you want to move to a shared server, you can use 'git clone --bare' instead of 'git init --bare'.

Comment: @Garrett Hyde: Nice; I didn't know that.

Comment: One difference between cloning on the server rather than on the client, though: Cloning configures a reference to the remote server.  If you `git init` local and then clone on the server, the *server* will list *you* as a remote repository.  You, as the client, will have to manually add the server as a remote repository.